# break statement inside switch case don't have effect in infinite loop

Tags: go, infinite-loop

In below piece of code, I am unable to understand why the `break` statement in `default` is not sufficient to end infinite loop. [PlayGroundLink](https://play.golang.org/p/lGPoZd34fxt)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for { //infinite loop
        fmt.Print("Enter Choice")
        userChoice := 3 //Intenssionaly given value here for testing
        switch userChoice {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println("Enter Radios of Circle:")
        case 2:
            fmt.Println("Enter Radios of Circle:")
        default:
            fmt.Println("\nExiting...")
            break  // this break is executing , but why it is not coming out of infinte 'for' loop ?
        }

    }
}
```

OutPut of above Code (Not Ending .. keep on going )

```
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
Enter Choice
Exiting...
```

Comment: That breaks from the `switch`: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements

Comment: Okay !! I added label to solve the issue!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a label to your loop, you can explicitly `break` from the loop:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    Loop:
        for { //infinite loop
            fmt.Print("Enter Choice")
            userChoice := 3 //Intenssionaly given value here for testing
            switch userChoice {
            case 1:
                fmt.Println("Enter Radios of Circle:")
            case 2:
                fmt.Println("Enter Radios of Circle:")
            default:
                fmt.Println("\nExiting...")
                break Loop
            }

        }
    fmt.Println("Outside the loop!")
}
```

Here's [a working example](https://play.golang.org/p/Gp5R2wXM4Ye)